# Summation of array items logical error

Tags: c++, arrays, sum

It should sum elements of the array of x from 135.1 to 24.1 and the output be 594.4
but the output is 570.3 which is the sum from 135.1 to 24.6 not 24.1
it works as the if condition is sum + x[i] smaller than 594.4 only and ignores the equal condition.
am very confused about it.

Code:

```
double x[12] = {135.1,73.1,63.2,59.1,59.1,53.1,36.1,35.1,31.8,24.6,24.1,50.2};

double sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)

    if (sum + x[i] <= 594.4)

        sum += x[i];

cout << sum << endl;
```

Comment: you told it not to add the last number with your if statement. Remeber that = is not exact for floating point. Why not take the if out

Comment: Errors due to floating point representation, and you're printing only a limited number of decimal places. The sum is actually something like `570.3000000000000682.......`. Adding `24.10000000000000142....` to that gives you `594.40000000000009094....` which is greater than `594.3999999999999772....` (I cut off the remaining decimal places, this is enough to illustrate what's actually happening).

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a precision issue on the double values.

Try to set your cutoff to 594.5 and see that you get the right result.

Answer (score 0):

> [Doubles are not floats, so don’t compare them](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/doubles-are-not-floats-so-dont-compare-them/)

Change you double comparing `==` included in `<=` to be something like,

```
bool areSame(double a, double b)
{
    return fabs(a - b) < EPSILON;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to print with more precision (with [std::setprecision()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/)), like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>      // std::setprecision

using namespace std;

int main() {
        double x[12] = {135.1,73.1,63.2,59.1,59.1,53.1,36.1,35.1,31.8,24.6,24.1$

        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                if (sum + x[i] <= 594.4) {
                        sum += x[i];
                }
        }
        cout << fixed << setprecision(10) << sum << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras-A15:~$ g++ -Wall main.cpp
gsamaras@gsamaras-A15:~$ ./a.out
570.3000000000
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It is a floating point issue in comparing two double values.